# Plugin or Observer for changes on product save?

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to add a product automatically to a category when custom attribute "new" is set and remove it when it is unset. I tried to do this via plugin aroundSave

but I'm only getting same values for "new" before and after the proceed() call:

```
class UpdateAttributes
{
    protected $logger;
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject
 * @param callable $proceed
 * @return |null
 */
public function aroundSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, callable $proceed)
{


    $beforeValue = $subject->getData('new');

    $this->logger->debug('BEFOOOOOOOOOOOORE :' );
    $this->logger->debug($beforeValue);
    $result = null;


    if($beforeValue){
        $result = $proceed();
    }



    $this->logger->debug('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFTER :' );
    $afterValue = $subject->getData('new');
    $this->logger->debug($afterValue);


    if ($result) {

        $this->_processData($beforeValue, $afterValue, $subject);
    }

    return $result;

}

protected function _processData($before, $after, $product){
    if($before != $after){
        $this->logger->debug('-----------NOT THE SAME -----------' );
        if($after == 1){
            $this->logger->debug('-----------ADD -----------' );
            $this->_addOrRemoveFromCategory($product, ['41']);
        }
        else{
            $this->logger->debug('-----------REMOVE -----------' );
            $this->_addOrRemoveFromCategory($product, ['41'], false);
        }
    }

}
protected function _addOrRemoveFromCategory($product, $categorieIds, $add = true){
    $toAddCategoryId = $categorieIds;

    $currentCatIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    if($add){
        $newCategoryIds = array_unique(
            array_merge(
                $currentCatIds,
                $toAddCategoryId
            )
        );
    }
    else{
        $newCategoryIds = $currentCatIds;
        foreach ($categorieIds as $id){
            $index = array_search($id, $currentCatIds);
            unset($newCategoryIds[$index]);
        }
    }

    $product->setCategoryIds($newCategoryIds);
}


}
```

Should I use another method or use an observer?

I'm pretty new to Magento and can't find proper literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with Observer.

Use event `catalog_product_save_after`

Put this `events.xml` in below path

`app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\etc\adminhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="test_name" instance="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULENAME\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And put your `Productsaveafter.php` in below path

`app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\Observer\`

```
<?php

namespace YOURNAMESPACE\YOURMODULENAME\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object
        $_sku=$_product->getSku(); // for sku

        // Do your Logic

        // Check OLD value for attribute 'new'
        $oldValue = $product->getOrigData('new');

        // New value for attribute 'new'
        $newValue = $product->getData('new');
    }   
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: i get the idea, but wouldnt i only get the state of attribute of the product AFTER the save? i need to compare attribute "new" before and after the save to see if it changes...

Comment: try using ```catalog_product_save_before``` event as well.

Comment: Works like a charme, thanks alot. Still wanna find out why it doesnt work with the plugin tho :)

Comment: Let me search it for you, pls mark it as a solution and up vote. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To change any code behaviour either you can use plugin or Observer.

Plugin:

- You can use **around** plugin to change the behaviour or code of the function but if you want to change response of the function you can use **after** plugin.
- But if you already have **Observer event** you can use that to change response of any event or function.

So, You can use event `**catalog_product_save_after**``

and just save update your product according to your state of the product.